# processing-rs stable build giving type annotation error

Tags: rust-cargo

I've been trying to make a simple Rust program using the [processing](https://crates.io/crates/processing) crate, however when I attempt running it, it throws `[E0283]` several times while attempting to include `cocoa`.
Here's all of the errors:

```
cargo run
   Compiling cocoa v0.14.0
   Compiling processing v0.3.2
   Compiling cocoa v0.11.0
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
   --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cocoa-0.14.0/src/appkit.rs:491:9
    |
491 |         msg_send![self, releaseGlobally];
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
    |
    = note: cannot satisfy `_: Any`
note: required by a bound in `__send_message`
   --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/objc-0.2.7/src/message/mod.rs:177:51
    |
175 | pub unsafe fn send_message<T, A, R>(obj: *const T, sel: Sel, args: A)
    |               ------------ required by a bound in this function
176 |         -> Result<R, MessageError>
177 |         where T: Message, A: MessageArguments, R: Any {
    |                                                   ^^^ required by this bound in `send_message`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `msg_send` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cocoa-0.14.0/src/appkit.rs:2810:9
     |
2810 |         msg_send![self, setBezelStyle:style];
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
     |
     = note: cannot satisfy `_: Any`
note: required by a bound in `__send_message`
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/objc-0.2.7/src/message/mod.rs:177:51
     |
175  | pub unsafe fn send_message<T, A, R>(obj: *const T, sel: Sel, args: A)
     |               ------------ required by a bound in this function
176  |         -> Result<R, MessageError>
177  |         where T: Message, A: MessageArguments, R: Any {
     |                                                   ^^^ required by this bound in `send_message`
     = note: this error originates in the macro `msg_send` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cocoa-0.14.0/src/appkit.rs:3415:9
     |
3415 |         msg_send![self, setEditable:editable];
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
     |
     = note: cannot satisfy `_: Any`
note: required by a bound in `__send_message`
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/objc-0.2.7/src/message/mod.rs:177:51
     |
175  | pub unsafe fn send_message<T, A, R>(obj: *const T, sel: Sel, args: A)
     |               ------------ required by a bound in this function
176  |         -> Result<R, MessageError>
177  |         where T: Message, A: MessageArguments, R: Any {
     |                                                   ^^^ required by this bound in `send_message`
     = note: this error originates in the macro `msg_send` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cocoa-0.14.0/src/appkit.rs:3418:9
     |
3418 |         msg_send![self, setStringValue:label];
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
     |
     = note: cannot satisfy `_: Any`
note: required by a bound in `__send_message`
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/objc-0.2.7/src/message/mod.rs:177:51
     |
175  | pub unsafe fn send_message<T, A, R>(obj: *const T, sel: Sel, args: A)
     |               ------------ required by a bound in this function
176  |         -> Result<R, MessageError>
177  |         where T: Message, A: MessageArguments, R: Any {
     |                                                   ^^^ required by this bound in `send_message`
     = note: this error originates in the macro `msg_send` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
   --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cocoa-0.11.0/src/appkit.rs:491:9
    |
491 |         msg_send![self, releaseGlobally];
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
    |
    = note: cannot satisfy `_: Any`
note: required by a bound in `__send_message`
   --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/objc-0.2.7/src/message/mod.rs:177:51
    |
175 | pub unsafe fn send_message<T, A, R>(obj: *const T, sel: Sel, args: A)
    |               ------------ required by a bound in this function
176 |         -> Result<R, MessageError>
177 |         where T: Message, A: MessageArguments, R: Any {
    |                                                   ^^^ required by this bound in `send_message`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `msg_send` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0283`.
error: could not compile `cocoa` (lib) due to 4 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cocoa-0.11.0/src/appkit.rs:2810:9
     |
2810 |         msg_send![self, setBezelStyle:style];
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
     |
     = note: cannot satisfy `_: Any`
note: required by a bound in `__send_message`
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/objc-0.2.7/src/message/mod.rs:177:51
     |
175  | pub unsafe fn send_message<T, A, R>(obj: *const T, sel: Sel, args: A)
     |               ------------ required by a bound in this function
176  |         -> Result<R, MessageError>
177  |         where T: Message, A: MessageArguments, R: Any {
     |                                                   ^^^ required by this bound in `send_message`
     = note: this error originates in the macro `msg_send` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cocoa-0.11.0/src/appkit.rs:3415:9
     |
3415 |         msg_send![self, setEditable:editable];
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
     |
     = note: cannot satisfy `_: Any`
note: required by a bound in `__send_message`
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/objc-0.2.7/src/message/mod.rs:177:51
     |
175  | pub unsafe fn send_message<T, A, R>(obj: *const T, sel: Sel, args: A)
     |               ------------ required by a bound in this function
176  |         -> Result<R, MessageError>
177  |         where T: Message, A: MessageArguments, R: Any {
     |                                                   ^^^ required by this bound in `send_message`
     = note: this error originates in the macro `msg_send` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/cocoa-0.11.0/src/appkit.rs:3418:9
     |
3418 |         msg_send![self, setStringValue:label];
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
     |
     = note: cannot satisfy `_: Any`
note: required by a bound in `__send_message`
    --> /Users/synnove/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/objc-0.2.7/src/message/mod.rs:177:51
     |
175  | pub unsafe fn send_message<T, A, R>(obj: *const T, sel: Sel, args: A)
     |               ------------ required by a bound in this function
176  |         -> Result<R, MessageError>
177  |         where T: Message, A: MessageArguments, R: Any {
     |                                                   ^^^ required by this bound in `send_message`
     = note: this error originates in the macro `msg_send` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: could not compile `cocoa` (lib) due to 4 previous errors
```

The only release version that I can find so far which doesn't throw these errors is version 0.1.0 which throws a separate error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `processing::Screen`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use processing::Screen;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Screen` in the root
```

Is there any way to resolve either of these errors?